# Import JSON via http vs require

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I came across two ways to import **local** json files to my code.

1. Using angulars `http get`.

Thats well known for loading json input. You can switch easily from remote to local json files.

2. Typescript `require`

Another way to load json in typescript files is via require. This is simple as I don't have to deal with `Promises/Observables`. I just include them like this:

```
data: any = require('assets/json/my.json');
```

I want to know something about the advantages and disadvantages between these two approaches. Is there a prefered way and why?

Comment: Another way is https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi it depends on your requirement.

If your file is constant, will not be changed then it is best option is to use .require()
 - .require() will cache your file, and when you import again it will give the cached file, so it might be bad option you want current time data because you will not get the updated data from that file

But if your file is getting updated then you have to use HTTP.